# Two-way syncing folders between PCs and smb share

Tags: sync, smb

I have a file server running OpenSolaris and couple of laptops plus a desktop all running Windows 7. I'd like to sync folders between the laptops and desktop via the server. What would be a good software to do this? Essentially any software that can do two-way sync between smb share and local folder would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)
>   allows the same version of files to be
>   maintained on multiple computing
>   devices. In other words, when two
>   devices are synchronized, the user can
>   be sure that the most current version
>   of a file is available on both
>   devices, regardless of where it was
>   last modified.

Answer (score -2):

There are a large number of programs that will do this (google file synchronisation / synchronization - depending on favoured spelling). One of many is my own program. Comment back here if you want me to say what it is.

Comment: Be nice for the downvoters to say why.  The point still stands, there are numerous options out there. Go look for them. I'm not pushing my own solution.